# What happens internally when a value to the variable is assigned and when it is scanned it from stdin?

Tags: c, memory, scanf

What actually happens in the memory when,

1. `int a;
   a=5;`
2. `int a;
   scanf("%d",&a);`

or why scanf uses & to take in values ?
Can anyone please.. explain ?

Comment: As we don't have the context of your homework, it is difficult to do it. Said that, we are no "do my homework" site.

Comment: @Olaf It is not a homework. Moreover, it doesn't matter whether it is a homework or not. I am trying to understand things.

Comment: This is explained in so many tutorials, C books, or on-line documentation...

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference if it is filled correctly by `scanf`, to ensure that, always check the result:

```
if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

If the user input is a valid number, it fills the content of the variable pointed by the first argument.

> Can anyone please.. explain ? (if possible diagrammatically)

Take a look to [Understanding the Stack](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

Comment: No diagram? Pew, that's not good, OP would have to work that out on his own for the homework ...

Comment: @Olaf Why are you certain it's a homework?

Comment: @machine_1: Common sense? Do you have more information proving me wrong?

Comment: @Olaf I don't intend to prove you wrong. I just think the above question could be a simple inquiry, and since the OP has not mentioned it's a homework, there is no need to insist!

Comment: @machine_1: I don't **insist**. I just suspected.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int *ptr=&a;
    scanf("%d",ptr);
    printf("%d",*ptr);
}
We should have been using scanf this way for clear understanding...I think.

Comment: You don't need to, passing the address with `&a` or passing an intermediate pointer results in the same.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening is needed to tell something what does mean variable, than say something about pointers and its types and finally explain how does `scanf` works and why is good habit to check its return value.

**Lets ask what is variable `a`?**

`a` is just named memory address. When you type in code `a` it basically says to compiler to get value which lays on that memory address, what is in your case value `5`.

So when you pass `a` to function you just pass value which is in your case 5.
When you want by function to write value into variable you have to pass pointer to your variable `a`.

**And what is a pointer?**

Pointer is just memory address with information about the type of data which lies on this memory address.

**Why you have to info compiler about the type?**

Because different types occupies different size in memmory (1B, 2B whatever).

Basically you specify the type of pointer in your function parameter. For example lets define function `f`

```
void f(int* b){
  b = 42;
}
```

and you call the function `f` like this:
    f(&a);
and after its call the value of variable `a` is `42`.
But function `scanf` is not this case continue reading...

**How does works function scanf?**

Function `scanf` is declared as:

```
int scanf ( const char * format, ... );
```

These `...` says that function accepts variable number of parameters. So is has at the beginning no info of types of parameters and its number. So you have to specify each type of each parameter in string `format` .

So when you write:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

you are saying: "Hey function `scanf` I am giving you address of my variable and please write me to this address value of number which `scanf` reads from standard input. And function know that pointer to variable `a` is type of `int` from format string `%d`.

**Don't forget to check return value of function scanf**

And in addition is good habit to check return value of function scanf which tells you if the the method succeeded or failed. (User can provide text "hello" instead of number.)

More info about the function scanf and its return value you can find [in documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

Comment: **So when you pass a to function you just pass value which is in your case 5. When you want by function to write value into variable you have to pass pointer to your variable a.**

Doubt: Why is that, for writing into a variable, we have to pass the pointer to the variable a? Isn't it possible to write to a memory [named **a** here] without pointers - just by writing scanf("%d",a);. Is it because conventionally scanf() was designed that way?
Does this mean that if the concept of pointers was not there, it would have been impossible to perform the I/O operations on C language ?

Comment: int a; a=5; --> In this the value 5 is known to the compiler while compilation, while scanf("%d",&a);-- in this the value to be given is unknown

Does the above point makes any relevance with the context ?

Comment: Its simple. When you want for function to return some value you have in C basically 2 options. You could use `return` statement or you provide function address where it could write value and using scanf("%d",&a); you are doing the second option.

Comment: C is just simple and "stupid" low level language that can't read somebody's mind to know that programmer wants to write to variable by providing just value of variable by typing `scanf("%d",a);`
Function in C does not known about other code around all it knows is provided by parameters. When you use `scanf("%d",a);` your PC try to write to address 5 and you probably get run-time error segmentation fault error because you probably try to write to other process memmory.